# jQuery: Add class if list item has checked radio button inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add an own class if a list item has an active radio button inside of it.

I tried this code to add a class but I guess there is an error in it:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  var check = $('.wc_payment_method').map(function(e) {
    return $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')
  }).get()

  $('.wc_payment_method').addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.wc_payment_method {padding: 10rem;}
.active {background-color: #eee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
  </li>

  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_creditcard">
    <input id="payment_method_creditcard" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="creditcard">
    <label for="payment_method_creditcard">Credit card</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('.input-radio:checked').each(function() { $(this).parent().addClass('active')});`

Comment: thanks! I tried it but it has no effect :-/

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add live code snippet by clicking on `<>` menu.

Comment: done, is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes. Also add the corresponding CSS class `active` in the snippet.

Comment: done, it works in that example but not on my side?! But I get no errors?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Loop your inputs using `.each()`
- go for `$(this).closest('selector')`  to target the closest selector
- use `.toggleClass('className', Boolean)` to toggle the class.

```js
const $inp = $('[name="payment_method"]');

$inp.on("change", function() {
  $inp.each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.wc_payment_method').toggleClass('active', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.active { background: gold; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
  </li>

  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_creditcard">
    <input id="payment_method_creditcard" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="creditcard">
    <label for="payment_method_creditcard">Credit card</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or don't use JavaScript at all:

- Use the `:checked` pseudo
- Target the sibling Label element General Sibling Combinator selector `~`

```css
/* Style the adjacent LABEL instead */
.input-radio:checked ~ label {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_paypal">
    <input id="payment_method_paypal" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="paypal">
    <label for="payment_method_paypal">PayPal</label>
  </li>

  <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_creditcard">
    <input id="payment_method_creditcard" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="creditcard">
    <label for="payment_method_creditcard">Credit card</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your code but it doesn't show any effect. But also no errors?! CSS is no option because I need to add a style to the parent element.

Comment: @Cray strange, I provided you working snippets and works like a charm. I cannot guess.

Comment: @Cray This seems to work as you stated in the question. The reason your code does not work is because you're applying class to all elements. If this is not working, please add description of what is happening.

Comment: @Cray There's 4 lines of JS, please study it  - and try to figure out the needed changes you need to apply to your code. Perhaps it's just matter of changing a selector.

Comment: Thanks, I will check if there is any difference to my code. @Tushar what do you mean with "The reason your code does not work is because you're applying class to all elements"?

Thanks again to you both!

Comment: Probably that comment should have been on the question. It means in `$('.wc_payment_method').addClass('active');`, the selector will select all `li` elements having this class. This is the reason, the class is applied to all `li`s irrespective of the radio inside it is checked or not.